# Dropdown list to JavaScript array to fill text boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I am trying to display a MySQL table on a job sheet system form that I am making the drop down list shows the customer details and then once selected the fields should be filled in on the main form.

I know people tend to use AJAX but this is to be used on a tablet tethered to a mobile and want to ask the server as little as possible.

Because I have already got the details from the SQL to display the drop down I thought I could use this. I found the original code at:

> http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10372137-RESOLVED-How-do-I-populate-multiple-text-boxes-from-a-dropdown-(I-can-populate-1-text-box!)

but I also want to display items that aren't on the dropdown list. Someone said it works but the more I have learned I couldn't see how because the array it was building just didn't seem to be in a JavaScript format.

I have the drop down working and also it fills a JavaScript array using names but I just cannot work out how to use the array to show in the fields.

It seems to be the named indexes used in the array. I can get a test array to display when I use the normal static array but I have commented them out but as soon as I try to use the names on the array I get undefined errors.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"> 




    <?php

      include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM customer";
            $result1 =($mysqli-> query($query1));


        // build javascript array building an object


        // build javascript array
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ 
          echo 'customer['.$row['customer_id'].'] = new Array(';
          echo 'customer['.$row['customer_id'].'][customer_id] = "'.$row['customer_id'].'";';
          echo 'customer['.$row['customer_id'].'][post_code] = "'.$row['post_code'].'";';
          echo 'customer['.$row['customer_id'].'][company_name] = "'.$row['company_name'].'");';
        }

        ?> 

    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <form name="customerform" form id="customerform"> 
<p>


    <select name="customerselect" id="customerselect" onChange="showname()"> 
        <option value="">Select customer</option> 

        <?php
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM customer";
            $result1 =($mysqli-> query($query1));

            // build javascript array
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ 
                echo'<option value="'.$row['customer_id'].'">'.$row['forename'].'">'.$row['surname'].'">'.$row['customer_name'].'</option>';
            }           

                        ?>
        </select>
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="cust" value="" id="cust" />

<input type="text" name="cust" value="" id="customerselected" />
<input type="text" name="post_code" value="" id="post_code" />
</p>
<p>update
  <input type="button" name="update" id="update" value="update" onClick="showname()">

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</p> 
    </form>


</body>

<script>    

        //var customer = Array();
        var customer = Array();
        //This below is a test multi dimensional Array which does work. //
        //customer['CCS'] = Array[{forename:'Robert', surname:'Grain', company:'HOMS'}];

    function showname() {


        //this var takes the result of the selected drop down list and shows the correct part of the array.
        var customerselected = document.getElementById('customer');
        customername = customerselected.value;

        // this does work but not from the array just fills the details up
        document.customerform.customerselected.value = customername;

        // the next part takes the selected dropdown data and calls for the correct place in the array
        // document.getElementById("cust").value = customer['CCS'][0];
        // document.getElementById("cust").value = customer[CCS]["forename"] ;
        // (customer[''][forename]);
         document.customerform.post_code.value = customer[customerselect]["post_code"];


    }

    window.onload=function() {
        showname();
    } 

</script>
</html>
```

This is the source code from Explorer in the console. from the JavaScript Array.

```
</body>
</html>customer[118] = new Array(customer[118][customer_id] = "118";customer[118][post_code] = "L37 4RG";customer[118][company_name] = "jc knight");customer[119] = new Array(customer[119][customer_id] = "119";customer[119][post_code] = "DE56 7HG";customer[119][company_name] = "farm Customer giles");customer[122] = new Array(customer[122][customer_id] = "122";customer[122][post_code] = "LE67 8FH";customer[122][company_name] = "a test company");
```

Also this dropdown list creates:

```
 <select name="customerselect" id="customer" onChange="showname()"> 
        <option value="">Select customer</option> 

        <option value="118">John">Knight"></option><option value="119">Bill">Giles"></option><option value="122">Robert">Grain"></option>       </select>
</p>
```

Maybe I should move the code to the bottom of the HTML for the JavaScript array although I wasn't sure if this wouldn't be initialised when required because it has ran the HTML first. I'm a little unsure if the order of things were correct.

The error I receive happens as soon as I change the drop downlist and it shows the following:

```
      document.customerform.post_code.value = customer['customerselect'][post_code];
}

X 'post_code' is undefined
```

[image: Error I recieve]

I think somewhere I am getting my document.value wrong when showing my array ?

Comment: Can we see a sample of the JavaScript arrays added to the HTML? Have you used 'View Source' to check it is rendering OK? Are there any JS errors on page load?

Comment: Could the `customer` initialisation in the later part of your code be overwriting the PHP-written JS at the start?

Comment: Hello halfer I have pressed F12 in explorer and it shows the following  .                                   
</html>customer[118] = new Array(customer[118][customer_id] = "118";customer[118][post_code] = "L37 4RG";customer[118][company_name] = "jc knight");customer[119] = new Array(customer[119][customer_id] = "119";customer[119][post_code] = "DE56 7HG";customer[119][company_name] = "farm Customer giles");customer[122] = new Array(customer[122][customer_id] = "122";customer[122][post_code] = "LE67 8FH";customer[122][company_name] = "a test company");

Comment: ^ That's not very readable in an unformatted comment. Would you add it to the end of your question please, formatted? Thanks. (Also, I appear to have received a message notification, but nevertheless when replying to individuals, please use their handle e.g. @halfer - you get tab completion too).

Comment: (It's worth notifying people about edits you make, otherwise they are likely to be missed). Thanks for the edit - I can see the problem. The JavaScript array does not appear to be in `<script>` tags, and in any case appears after the closing `</html>` tag. You need to move this to be inside a script tag in the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks smftre for that. In the end I have opted for the jquery and ajax. and I think it has worked out betted for it originally I was trying to make the code as efficient as possible on bandwidth because the system is to be used but ajax seems to be the standard for a reason and works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather don't hope that a constant will work here.
Instead try the below as a replacement:

```
    // build javascript array
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ ?>
      var customer["<?=$row['customer_id']?>"] = [];
      customer["<?=$row['customer_id'];?>"]['customer_id'] = "<?=$row['customer_id'];?>";
      customer["<?=$row['customer_id'];?>"]['post_code'] = "<?=$row['post_code'];?>";
      customer["<?=$row['customer_id'];?>"]['company_name'] = "<?=$row['company_name'];?>";
    <? }
```

Comment: Thanks smftre for that. In the end I have opted for the jquery and ajax. and I think it has worked out betted for it originally I was trying to make the code as efficient as possible on bandwidth because the system is to be used but ajax seems to be the standard for a  reason and works very well.